# Reading/Writing to binary file

Tags: java, file, binary

right now I have to read/write an array of objects to a binary file. I have the code in place, but for some reason I am getting a write error (an error that I created in my try catch). Any solutions for how to fix this are appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class Trivia {
private String question;
private String answer;
private int points;

public Trivia() {
    question = " ";
    answer = " ";
    points = 0;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public String getAnswer() {
    return answer;
}

public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}

public void setQuestion(String q) {
    question = q;
}

public void setAnswer(String a) {
    answer = a;
}

public void setPoints(int p) {
    points = p;
}

}

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Driver  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "trivia.dat";
    Trivia[] t = new Trivia[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t[i] = new Trivia();
    }

    t[0].setQuestion("How many states are in the US?");
    t[0].setAnswer("50");
    t[0].setPoints(1);

    t[1].setQuestion("What is the capital of Michigan?");
    t[1].setAnswer("Lansing");
    t[1].setPoints(1);

    t[2].setQuestion("How many senators come from each state?");
    t[2].setAnswer("2");
    t[2].setPoints(2);

    t[3].setQuestion("What is the largest state?");
    t[3].setAnswer("Alaska");
    t[3].setPoints(2);

    t[4].setQuestion("Who was the thrid president?");
    t[4].setAnswer("Thomas Jefferson");
    t[4].setPoints(3);

    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;

    try{
        outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("trivia.dat"));

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Could not open file");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try{
        outputStream.writeObject(t);
        outputStream.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Writing error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;

    try{
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("trivia.dat"));

    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
     Trivia[] test = null;

     try{
         test = (Trivia[])inputStream.readObject();
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Reading error");
         System.exit(0);
     }



}
}
```

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: Show us some stack trace

Comment: I said it above. I am getting "Writing error". It's already in the code `}catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Writing error");
        System.exit(0);
    }`

Comment: The good thing about exceptions is that they contain an error message and a stack trace. You should use this information like `e.printStackTrace()` to print the stack trace to the console. So please change your code and try to understand the error message. Maybe this solve your problem directly. Otherwise post the stacktrace here and mark the line, where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Trivia` class has to implement the `Serializable` interface to allow writing it using an `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Same thing, after implementing it I still get my "Writing error"\

Comment: Really? Hm. I couldn't tell you what's going on. This is what I changed it to. `public class Driver implements Serializable`

Comment: @ProgrammingGuy123 I said `Trivia` has to implement the interface NOT `Driver` ;-)

Comment: Ah, so no more errors anymore. But, now that it actually runs, my trivia.dat file is still empty even after it is supposed to have been written to.

Comment: How did you check that it's empty?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I had another file open, not my trivia file. In my JRE system library on Eclipse I have the trivia.dat file. I just click it and it has the binary jibberish

Comment: Good - so everything is fine now?  :)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I didn't know about the serializeable.

Answer (score 0):

Always do a printStackTrace() in your catch clause to understand what's going on.

You may have understand by yourself that your Trivia class does not implement `java.io.Serializable`.

Comment: "Always do a printStackTrace()" or just don't catch, let it bubble up